# How to know the correct position of satellites with PyEphem?

Tags: python, position, pyephem

PyEpehm regards the earth as the sphere, but I want to know correct latitude and longitude of satellites with PyEpem considering oblateness of the earth. Do you have any ideas about it?

Comment: Currently, i think it's not documented in PyEphem's documentation. So, no, i think it's not possible just yet.